# dovecot confusing site cert with mail cert

Tags: ssl, certificates, dovecot

I'll try to keep this short. I want beta.example.com to use my server as a mail server. I see that dovecot and postfix have only one line for a certificate. So I made a cert for mail.example.com which is completely valid. I tried using thunderbird to connect to my mail server (beta.example.com) and it gave me a incorrect domain warning saying the cert belongs to mail.example.com. Where did I mess up? The mx record says mail.example.com so shouldn't it know the cert is for mail.example.com? I added an exception however it still fails (after it prompts me for my password). I looked at my server and it appears dovecot is rejecting the connection because thunderbird is giving it bad cert data.

Answer (score 3):

You experience the very purpose of certificates: preventing to accidentally connect with a server that isn't the one you expect (`mail.example.com` instead of `beta.example.com`). You must configure a certificate issued for the domain you connect to, ie. if the mail client connects to `beta.example.com`, you need a certificate for `beta.example.com`.

Either get another certificate for `beta.example.com` (or include it as subject alternative name), or have `mail.example.com` point to the IP of `beta.example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

The client is configured to connect to `mail.example.com`.

The server it connects to claims (in the certificate) to be `beta.example.com`.

Because `mail.example.com` is not the same thing as `beta.example.com`, the client complains about the mismatch. **This is entirely by design.**

To get this to work, **you need to configure your mail server to present a certificate that includes a Subject Alternative Name that matches the host name that the client is pointed at.** How that host name ends up being resolved to an IP address is beside the point.

It used to be that you would put the host name in the Common Name field of the certificate, but this practice is being deprecated. You can still put the host name as the certificate's CN if you want to, but for best compatibility you need to *also* put it as a SAN. I believe most CAs will put the CN as a SAN as a service to you if you don't do so yourself in your CSR, but there's the risk that some might not; check your certificate.

If you must use the *same certificate* for Postfix and Dovecot, but for some reason you want to have *different host names* published for the two (say `smtp.example.com` and `pop.example.com`), then you need a certificate that is valid for both host names involved. This can be done with a multiple-hostname certificate or a wildcard (`*.example.com`) certificate.

---

Also, **MX (mail exchanger) DNS RRs are really only relevant for incoming SMTP connections to a mail server handling mail for a particular domain, where the remote mail server initially knows only the recipient domain.** It's perfectly valid to have for example

```
example.com. MX 0 mail.example.com.
mail.example.com. CNAME beta.example.com.
beta.example.com. A 192.0.2.123
```

though not really recommended because pointing a RR at a non-canonical RR can make some resolvers choke. However, if the remote system's resolver accepts it (most do), the above is effectively the same as if you'd had

```
example.com. MX 0 mail.example.com.
mail.example.com. A 192.0.2.123
```

In both cases, the remote MTA (mail transfer agent; in modern days, a mail server speaking SMTP to other mail servers) will be connecting to mail.example.com (because that is the host name of the MX as given in the MX RR), and thus will be expecting a certificate that is valid for mail.example.com.

**Your MUA won't be consulting the MX records** and won't know either way; it will be consulting the address (`A`, `AAAA` and in rare cases maybe also `A6`; A6 RRs are deprecated, but were used for some time for IPv6) records of whatever host name you give it as the incoming (POP/IMAP) or outgoing (SMTP) mail server.